# VM keeps timing out due to SSL warning

Tags: apache, ubuntu, vagrant

When i try and access my VM from the web browser, I get the following error:

```
This webpage is not available
ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT
```

This is the the contents of the error.log file:

```
[Wed Feb 03 12:21:34.321525 2016] [core:notice] [pid 5101] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Wed Feb 03 12:21:59.267496 2016] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 5101] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Wed Feb 03 12:22:00.257480 2016] [ssl:warn] [pid 10050] AH01906: RSA server certificate is a CA certificate (BasicConstraints: CA == TRUE !?)
[Wed Feb 03 12:22:00.286850 2016] [ssl:warn] [pid 10051] AH01906: RSA server certificate is a CA certificate (BasicConstraints: CA == TRUE !?)
[Wed Feb 03 12:22:00.288822 2016] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 10051] AH00163: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) OpenSSL/1.0.1f configured -- resuming normal operations
```

What is causing this issue? am I missing something simple?

Comment: can you start apache from command line normally - you see if it crashes right away (pbm with conf file) or on a specific request

Comment: It does not crash at all, its starts with out issue

Comment: the issue is `[pid 5101] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down` which kills the apache process so need to find out why, if it starts fine, can you point your browser to it ?

Comment: thats the error log from apache. It is possible the issue is not with apache,but with something else, but the apache log was the thing that I was hoping would tell me the issue.

`> service apache2 status`
`* apache2 is running`

Comment: its possible its not with apache directly but I mean as long as it runs you should be able to access the server from browser on the host, right ?

Comment: I am able to ssh into the VM. but  am not able to access the VM from the browser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out, it was because of a firewall.

I turned off the firewall (I'm developing on a local VM) and it worked without issue.

```
sudo ufw disable
```